# aws sns, sqs and ec2 within single region for push messaging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am willing to make a simple chat application in django.

After user sends message and the message in saved in `Message` model I would like to signal the publish event so that my mobile app gets message.

I went throught the `SNS` documentation and in its pricing I found `Data transferred between Amazon SNS and Amazon EC2 within a single region is free of charge (i.e., $0.00 per GB)`

My api is/will be hosted in `ec2` in the same region lets say at `Singapore` the same region as `sns`. If I publish a event which I receive a message in my mobile application , will that cost me  or it is considered as same region ? If it does than building a chat application using `SNS` will be very expensive.

If anyone can meke me clear about it that would be so helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think it will be free even if they are in the same region but their prices for SNS are too low, if in free tier of Amazon you won't be charged for

> 1,000,000 Requests of Amazon Simple Queue Service every month**
>
> 1,000,000 Requests, 100,000 HTTP notifications and 1,000 email
>   notifications for Amazon Simple Notification Service every month**

as the SNS pricing suggests. Going above the limits will cost you :

> It costs $1.00 to send one million mobile push notifications ($0.50 per million publishes, plus $0.50 per million mobile push notification deliveries). When you use SNS topics to broadcast identical messages to many recipients at once.